# Rescaling image make it black in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have come up with a function which transform the width and height of an image to new values,

```
function imageToDataUri(src, width, height) {

    // create an off-screen canvas
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=src;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // set its dimension to target size
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    var d = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    console.log('de from transformation is');
    console.log(d);

    return canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

The input to the function is a base64 string and the output is the same as well, but sometimes above function gives me a complete black image when I use my input image. Can someone tell me is there anything I am missing in my codes?

Comment: you can't do that with images you don't own (cross site images) ... those images are tainted, no data you can play with. It's for copyright reasons.

Comment: what would be the alternative then?

Comment: host your own images, or proxy requests via your server where your site runs. this is about copyright infringement, watch out your requirements.

Comment: I am not sure at all if this is due to cross site images since I don't get any log error regarding that..and sometime my function works..

Comment: it's about tainted canvas. it works when you are allowed to draw images from your site or foreign sites. It doesn't when you are not allowed. There's no magic involved. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: P.S. if you don't have any error, as you stated, it might be that the image is not recognized (not a PNG or a JPEG, maybe something else). I don't think there are other use cases where a canvas would give you black results.